# AngularJS File Upload, uploaded image is blank?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I'm using angular to upload file to parse.com rest api.

I follow this tutorial [AngularJS Upload tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm) and REST upload documentation here [REST Upload](https://parseplatform.github.io//docs/rest/guide/#uploading-files)

Then I modify my code. Here is my code looks like.

```
//below code inside RegisterController
    $scope.upload = function () {

            //upload file
            var file = $scope.myFile;

         console.log('file is ' );
         console.dir(file);
         console.log(file.name);

         var uploadUrl = "http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/files/"+file.name; //added file.name
         fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            //end upload file

    }
//above code inside RegisterController

//below code outside any controller
rentalkika.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
         var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
         var modelSetter = model.assign;

         element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
               modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
         });
      }
   };
}]);

rentalkika.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
   this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('file', file);

      $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
         transformRequest: angular.identity,
         headers: {
            'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'secret',  //added this
            'Content-Type': undefined
            }
      })

      .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      })

      .error(function(){
      });
   }
}]);
//above code outside any controller
```

Here is my HTML

```
<form ng-controller="RegisterController">
<label>Upload file</label>
                     <input type="file" name="ktp" file-model="myFile">                      

                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">Get hot offers via e-mail
                </label>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click="upload()" class="btn btn-primary">
                </form>
```

It successfully upload file indicated with `201 created` status code and I get success response including name and image url.

The image looks like this [blank image](http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/files/gMKfl1wDyk3m6I5x0IrIjJyI87sumz58/67c8e24d54ad3f24371103a12b499a9d_anniv.jpg)

Is something missing or wrong with my code?

Comment: check file location image located in this http://128.199.249.233:1337/parse/files/ location

Comment: this is your file name gMKfl1wDyk3m6I5x0IrIjJyI87sumz58/67c8e24d54ad3f24371103a12b499a9d_anniv.jpg

Comment: @Pravin what do you mean?

Comment: any console log errors in browser ?

Comment: @Thanigainathan solved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happen because your binary data of image not sent.
Then I use this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and little bit configuration for headers.

And it works.